# How to vertically center pseudo element on transform rotate in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, pseudo-element

I'm having trouble on how to achieve making the X stay at the middle during transform. It looks like the issue only occur in Firefox browser between Chrome and FF.

I'm using FF Quantum 58.0.2 and the X moves to the top, in Chrome I have no issues.

I tried to add `top: 50%;` in the pseudo element selector but during rotation the X moves few pixels to the bottom. Is there any other way to achieve this in Firefox like it does in Chrome?

```css
.close >.x-button{
  width: 0.5em;
  height: 0.5em;
  position: relative; 
  background-color: #343a40;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0.5em 0em;
  transition: all 500ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-out;
  transform-origin: center center;
}
.close >.x-button::before,
.close >.x-button::after{
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.08em;
}
.close:hover >.x-button{
    border-radius: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    -ms-transform: scale(1.8) rotateZ(-360deg);
    -o-transform: scale(1.8) rotateZ(-360deg);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.8) rotateZ(-360deg);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.8) rotateZ(-360deg);
    transform: scale(1.8) rotateZ(-360deg);
}
.close:hover >.x-button::before,
.close:hover >.x-button::after {
  background-color: #FD0030;
}
.close >.x-button::before{
 -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
 transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.close >.x-button::after{
 -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
 transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<button class="close">
  <span class="x-button"></span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can vertically center the before and after like you do with any position absolute elements

Give it a `top: 50%` and `transform: translateY(-50%)`

I verified this on Mac FF

```css
.close >.x-button{
  width: 0.5em;
  height: 0.5em;
  position: relative; 
  background-color: #343a40;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0.5em 0em;
  transition: all 500ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-out;
  transform-origin: center center;
}
.close >.x-button::before,
.close >.x-button::after{
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.08em;
  top: 50%;
}
.close:hover >.x-button{
    border-radius: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    -ms-transform: scale(1.8) rotateZ(-360deg);
    -o-transform: scale(1.8) rotateZ(-360deg);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.8) rotateZ(-360deg);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.8) rotateZ(-360deg);
    transform: scale(1.8) rotateZ(-360deg);
}
.close:hover >.x-button::before,
.close:hover >.x-button::after {
  background-color: #FD0030;
}
.close >.x-button::before{
 -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
 transform: rotate(45deg) translateY(-50%);
}
.close >.x-button::after{
 -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
 transform: rotate(-45deg) translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<button class="close">
  <span class="x-button"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: The x looks distorted on my end.. I placed the `translateY(-50%)` instead outside the hover state, and it looks fine now. Thank you!

Comment: Oh I see, on mac the x looks the same on chrome and ff so I assumed it was the way it was supposed to be

Answer (score 1):

You could also add `bottom: 0.20em` on

```
.close >.x-button::before,
.close >.x-button::after
```

to fix it on all browsers.

Why `.20em`? `.25em` is half the icon's dimension and `.5em` is half the top and bottom margin.

Firefox:
[image]

Snippet:

```css
.close>.x-button {
  width: 0.5em;
  height: 0.5em;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #343a40;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0.5em 0em;
  transition: all 500ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-out;
  transform-origin: center center;
}

.close>.x-button::before,
.close>.x-button::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.08em;
  /* new */
  bottom: .20em;
}

.close:hover>.x-button {
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  -ms-transform: scale(1.8) rotateZ(-360deg);
  -o-transform: scale(1.8) rotateZ(-360deg);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.8) rotateZ(-360deg);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.8) rotateZ(-360deg);
  transform: scale(1.8) rotateZ(-360deg);
}

.close:hover>.x-button::before,
.close:hover>.x-button::after {
  background-color: #FD0030;
}

.close>.x-button::before {
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.close>.x-button::after {
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<button class="close">
  <span class="x-button"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: wow this is even neat. I never thought about that. Thank you!